# Combine 2 Queries with 1 Column into 1 output of 2 Columns

Tags: sql

I have 2 queries each return the same 6 rows with the top row being different in each.
I would like to combine them into 1 output of 2 columns.

When I try varying solutions, I get multiple iterations because of different combinations.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the data output I am currently seeing:

```
UID     username
%       All Incomplete Tasks
arthur  All Incomplete Tasks
jane    All Incomplete Tasks
john    All Incomplete Tasks
mary    All Incomplete Tasks
susan   All Incomplete Tasks
%       arthur
arthur  arthur
jane    arthur
john    arthur
mary    arthur
susan   arthur
%       jane
arthur  jane
jane    jane
john    jane
mary    jane
susan   jane
%       john
arthur  john
jane    john
john    john
mary    john
susan   john
%       mary
arthur  mary
jane    mary
john    mary
mary    mary
susan   mary
%       susan
arthur  susan
jane    susan
john    susan
mary    susan
susan   susan
```

This what I would like to see:

```
UID     username
%       All Incomplete Tasks
arthur  arthur
jane    jane
john    john
mary    mary
susan   susan
```

This is the current query I am using:

```
SELECT x.UID, y.username FROM
(SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT username as UID
FROM            dbo.goldusers_users
UNION SELECT '%' as UID) as x
,
(SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT username
FROM            dbo.goldusers_users
UNION SELECT 'All Incomplete Tasks' as username) as y
```

Comment: Please EDIT your post.  Post the query you have tried.  Also show sample of data records you have, and also what you WANT when complete.  Do as text, dont do pictures.  Simple formatting can be done with curly brackets above editor box.

Comment: So, the desired result is 6 rows? 7 rows? Please add sample data and the desired result to your request.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table table1 (col1 integer);
insert into table1 (col1) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);

create table table2 (col2 integer);
insert into table2 (col2) values (7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12);
```

And now you join by using the ROW_NUMBER to match each row to each other :

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2
FROM (
    SELECT col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS rn
    FROM table1
) t1
JOIN (
    SELECT col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col2) AS rn
    FROM table2
) t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

it returns:

```
 col1 | col2 
------+------
    1 |    7
    2 |    8
    3 |    9
    4 |   10
    5 |   11
    6 |   12
```